# SAS-How to calculate observations with certain lags

Tags: sas, lag

Suppose the dataset has two columns

```
Date   Time     Price  
01-03  11:00      1
01-03  11:02      2
01-03  11:02      3
01-03  11:03      4
01-03  11:07      5
01-04  11:00      4
01-04  11:01      6
01-04  11:01      7
```

I need to add a new column that equals to the posted price in the most recently minutes in the same day. If this minutes has multiple price, it should select the first one. For example

```
Date   Time     Price   New
01-03  11:00      1      2
01-03  11:02      2      4
01-03  11:02      3      4
01-03  11:03      4      5
01-03  11:07      5      . 
01-04  11:00      4      6
01-04  11:01      6      .
01-04  11:01      7      .
```

I use the code (`by date; if first.time;`) to solve the problem of multiple date. Since the gap between time is not fixed, I cannot use lag function in this case. So I don't know how to select the first price in next most recently minute. Could anyone give me some solutions? THX

Comment: Do you have SAS ETS? You can look at proc expand to 'look ahead'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just base SAS, this isn't particularly hard, though this isn't the most efficient method if you have very large datasets, this should perform okay in general.

We iterate over the dataset starting at the following row, until we find a row that has either a different time OR a different date.  If different time, save that price as the new price, and if different date (or EOF) clear the new price variable.

```
data have;
input Date :$5. Time :time5. Price;
format time time5.;
datalines;
01-03  11:00      1
01-03  11:02      2
01-03  11:02      3
01-03  11:03      4
01-03  11:07      5
01-04  11:00      4
01-04  11:01      6
01-04  11:01      7 
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have nobs=nobs;
  do _i = _n_ to nobs until (new_date ne date or new_time > time);
    set have(rename=(date=new_date price=new_price time=new_time)) point=_i;
  end;
  if (date ne new_date) or (_i > nobs) then call missing(new_price);  *times that it searched beyond limits;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, this code looks great. Would you mind if I ask a further question. What if I want to get the new price with fixed time interval, like five minutes after the observation?

Comment: Just add that to the until clause - `until new_time ge time+300` or whatever is appropriate.  This starts to have worse performance though compared to other solutions once you start tracking further down the datasets from the current row.